# Python win32api event shift not releasing key when other text is added

Tags: python, windows, winapi, windows-10

**Major Edit** Narrowed down the replication considerably

I am having issues with using shift in Python using the win32api keybd_event in Windows 10.

I want to be able to key down on shift, and then key up on shift.

The following file works as expect exactly as is. It pressed shift, then releases shift. (`160` is key code for left shift)

```
import time
import win32con
import win32api
from win32api import keybd_event, mouse_event

time.sleep(3)
keybd_event(160, 0, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)
keybd_event(160, 0, 2, 0)
time.sleep(1)
```

When I add the following to the end however, shift stays on key down for the rest of the program as well as after program execution until the active window is changed. (`84` is key code for t)

```
keybd_event(84, 0, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)
keybd_event(84, 0, 2, 0)
time.sleep(1)
```

This is as bare bones as I can replicate the issue with all abstraction removed. This is critically breaking what I'm trying to do and I can't make progress.

**Why is key up on shift not working when there is other keyboard actions happening?**

**UPDATE**

Passing in bScan key codes gives same behavior that code is below

```
time.sleep(3)
keybd_event(160, 0x10, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)
keybd_event(160, 0x10, 2, 0)
time.sleep(1)

keybd_event(84, 0x54, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)
keybd_event(84, 0x54, 2, 0)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You are passing `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` to [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx), but aren't providing a *bScan* parameter. What's the rationale behind this? And in case you are trying to automate a UI, you should really be using the proper way to do it: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: I am passing `EXTENDEDKEY `? I thought `keybd_event(160, 0, 2, 0)` was key up. I'm unfamiliar with bScan, I'll look into it. The reason I am automating the keyboard and mouse is because this is interacting with an external program of which I'm not allowed to tap into it's code (Starcraft 2 bot, Terms of Use forbids that) EDIT: I'm having issue finding a scan code for lshift. I found a table, but had no value for lshift.

Comment: @IInspectable I have passed bScan codes and I am still receiving the same behavior.

Comment: Why are you passing the same scan code for `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` without also setting the `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag? You need to thoroughly digest the documentation. Keyboard input is anything but trivial. At any rate, I'm not too fond of helping a cheater cheat. You'll just have to hope for help from someone else.

Comment: @IInspectable it's not for cheating. It's for an AI. Can you point me to the documentation. I'm new to python. This is all I've found. http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__keybd_event_meth.html

Comment: @IInspectable again, thanks for your help, it's all working, of proof of my intentions, see the project on github. https://github.com/goosehub/raynor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following works. Not sure why, would accept an answer that includes an explanation would be useful, or a link to the documentation for these functions.

```
import time
import win32con
import win32api
from win32api import keybd_event, mouse_event

time.sleep(3)
keybd_event(160, 0, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)

keybd_event(160, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY  | 
win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
time.sleep(1)

keybd_event(84, 0, 1, 0)
time.sleep(1)
keybd_event(84, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY  | 
win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
time.sleep(1)
```